# Direct experimental proof of relativity of simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

Special relativity predicts that for me and my friend who's running at a uniform speed of $v$ away from me, the same things don't happen at the same time. For instance, if my friend runs at a light bulb who's set to light up in a few seconds, the light bulb is going to light up 'earlier' for my friend. Is it possible to test this experimentally?

Comment: It seems as though you mixing up two different ideas (1) time dilation and (2) relativity of simultaneity. Time dilation is measured every day by GPS satellites so there is no lack of experimental evidence for it. Relativity of simultaneity is rather harder to measure experimentally. Can you clarify which you are asking about?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I was asking about relativity of simultaneity.

Comment: Thank you for the link I will look into that. My precise confusion is about the fact that we can't directly test the simultaneity of two events that take place at different locations because information can't travel faster than light, we can only make deductions.

Comment: About that 'already has answers here' link. The accepted answer there cites Sagnac effect synchronization as an instance of relativity of simultaneity whereas in fact Sagnac effect synchronization procedure and Einstein synchronization procedure will give different results.

Answer (score 0):

Relatity of simultaneity is not something you should even want to test; relativity of simultaneity isn't like that.

To explain that I need to describe a setup that implements a particular synchronization scenario. I need to describe this in order to contrast it with a relativity of simultaneity scenario.

Imagine a series of time keeping stations, distributed along the equator. Let's say 12 stations, all around the equator. In this thought experiment they want to maintain synchronized time-keeping to the degree of accuracy of atomic clocks. They establish a ring of connections and all stations start sending pulses in both directions. They agree to tune the timing between the pulses in such a way that in the clockwise and anti-clockwise directions the *same amount of pulses is circumnavigating the equator*.

The pulses can be packets of bits (just like internet packets of bits). So the time keeping stations, in this bi-directional relay, can keep count of the packets being relayed.

Since the Earth is rotating: when an eastward traveling pulse has completed a circumnavigation the stations are a bit further east. So for the eastward traveling pulses the time to complete a full relay course is longer than for the westward traveling pulses.

Using the information obtained with this procedure the 12 stations can arrive at a synchronized time (and incidentally they can infer the Earth rotation rate from the eastward/westward difference). Importantly: this special procedure isn't [Einstein synchronization procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation).

The thing that special about this configuration is that a loop is closed.

With the above in place I turn to relativity of simultaneity.

The standard way to describe relativity of simultaneity is an entirely linear case.

Let's say you have a fleet of spaceships, arranged in a line, let's call that the Red fleet. A second linear fleet, Green fleet, is oriented parallel, moving past the Red fleet.

The spaceships of the Red fleet can set up Einstein synchronization procedure to establish a synchronized fleet time. Likewise, the ships of the Green fleet can set up Einstein synchronization procedure to establish a synchronized fleet time. As we know, the Red fleet and the Green fleet will not arrive at the same simultaneity.

But note especially the following thing: the commander of the Green fleet has the option to decree that the Green fleet should switch to the same simultaneity as the Red fleet. Of course, that means that the clocks of the green fleet will no longer be in Einstein synchronized configuration. But no law of nature is violated. The clocks of the Green fleet will still all count the same amount of proper time, it's just that all communication involving time now has to take into acount that the clocks aren't synchonized to a common time. But each ship of Green fleet can accommodate the difference by being aware of it's own position relative to the other ships.

(And of course by symmetry all of the above applies the same for the Red fleet.)

What this demonstrates is the following: while the clock coordination that is established with Einstein synchronization is certainly the most *practical* coordination, it isn't a law of physics. In the case of all motion being linear motion simultaneity is *inherently ambiguous*.

**Closing a loop**

I started this answer describing a loop-closing scenario. The time coordination that is available when closing a loop is called the [Sagnac effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect).

**Disallowing the loop**

The next step is to imagine what is still possible when closing the loop is disallowed. For example, make is so that there is no connection between station 12 and station 1, so that in effect station 12 and station 1 are end points.

Then the configuration is topologically the same as the linear case. Then the 12 station have to resort to the only practical synchronization that they can still do: Einstein synchronization. That synchronization will not arrive at the same simultaneity that they arrived at when they could close the loop. This illustrates again that the Einstein synchronization procedure is an optimum in terms of practicality and not a law of nature.